# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "boards_pkey"　エラーが出て捜査ができません。

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql

https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan
上のサイトを一通り終えて、サイトに表示されるboard1 の名前を"Anime & Manga"変更しようと思ってデータベースに入った後に

```
simplech_db-# update boards set board='Anime & Manga', display_name='Anime & Manga' where board='board1' and display_name='Board 1';
```

と入力したのですが

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "boards_pkey"
```

```
DETAIL: Key (board)=(Anime & Manga) already exists.
```

と表示されてできません。
また、一度消してやろうと思って

```
truncate table boards;
```

と入力したら

```
ERROR: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL: Table "posts" references "boards".
HINT: Truncate table "posts" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

と表示されました。どうやったら、できますか？

Comment: 関連 - https://teratail.com/questions/132013

Comment: 一連の(掲示板設置に関する)質問をteratailとのマルチポストで繰り返していますが、他方で受けたアドバイスを「ネットに書いてあった」で済ませたり、そのまま質問文に含める(質問者自身で試行錯誤したような印象を受けさせる)ような質問の仕方は、アドバイスをくれた人達に対して不誠実だと思います。マルチポスト自体は禁止されていなくても、自分から一言添えておくだけで印象が違います。なおteratail側ではマルチポストに関して[注意書き](https://teratail.com/help)がありますのでよく確認してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

まず、メッセージを理解しましょう。
「ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "boards_pkey"」
重複したキーの値は、boardsテーブルの主キーはユニークでなければならないという制約に反しています。
「DETAIL: Key (board)=(Anime & Manga) already exists.」
キー　boardの値が、”Anime & Manga”であるレコードは既に存在しています。

「どうやったら、できますか？」
既にある、boardの値が、”Anime & Manga”であるレコードを削除してください。
そうすれば、boardの値を”Anime & Manga”に変更してもキーの重複が起こりません。

Comment: どうやって入力したら、レコードを削除できますか？

Comment: え！　SQLのコマンドは理解してらっしゃるのですよね、”update boards set board='Anime & Manga', display_name='Anime & Manga' where board='board1' and display_name='Board 1';”なんて書けるし、"truncate table"もご存じだし。。。　　何が判らないのですか？？？

Answer (score 0):

> どうやったら、できますか？

以下のメッセージの意味ですが、

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "boards_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (board)=(Anime & Manga) already exists.
```

boards テーブルは、board列がプライマリキーとなっており、同じ値を設定することが禁止されています。
boards テーブルの既存行のboard列に"Anime & Manga"が設定されているため、エラーとなっているという意味だと思います。

また、以下のメッセージの意味ですが、

```
ERROR: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL: Table "posts" references "boards".
HINT: Truncate table "posts" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

boardsテーブルを参照している postsテーブルのデータを truncate できません。
boardsと同時にpostsテーブルもtruncateする場合は、 TRUNCATE TABLE boards CASCADE と使いましょうという意味だと思います。

私も知りませんでしたが、[PostgreSQLのドキュメント](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/10/html/sql-truncate.html)によると、
「TRUNCATEは、テーブルにON DELETEトリガがあっても、それを発行しません。」そうです。

そのため、
(ア)boardsテーブルに関連するテーブルの全データを削除しても良い場合は、以下を使用し、

```
TRUNCATE TABLE boards CASCADE;
```

(イ)既存行の"Anime & Manga"のみ削除する場合は、以下を使用したら良いと思います。
(関連テーブルには、ON DELETE CASCADE が設定されているため、関連データもあわせて削除されるはずです。)

```
DELETE FROM boards WHERE board = 'Anime & Manga'
```

(ア)(イ)のいずれかを実行後は、以下を実行できると思います。

```
update boards set board='Anime & Manga', display_name='Anime & Manga' where board='board1' and display_name='Board 1';
```

捜査がんばってください。

Comment: やってみたら、{UPDATE 1}　と表示されて成功した！と思って、サイトに行くと確かにboard名が変更されてました。けど、アクセスしたら{404 not found}　と表示されてします。